# Check if app was bought or not

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-pay

I'm searching if is possible to check if the current user of the app bought the app or not.

Now I want to change the paid app to free with in-purchased inside the app but the problem is what happens to the current user that he paid the app.

I don't know if I can get all app purchased by the user with his google account.

Comment: That would seem like a violation of privacy. You can probably do this, but I don't think that is the right approach

Comment: Google Play does not allow you to switch an app from paid to free or vice versa so you'll need to be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish: are you creating a whole new free app and want to migrate people over to it from the paid app?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have a paid app and now I want to change it to free app with in-purchased but I want that the all user the they paid the app keep the app payment. you know?